# Not able to deploying spring boot app (1.2.5) war in tomcat 8

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, spring-boot, hikaricp

I'm doing a web app using spring-boot 1.2.5, the application works perfectly when I use the embeded tomcat generating the jar file, however when I need to generate a war file and deploy it in tomcat I'm getting a tons of errors.

I follow this [instructions](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) but no success.  Here is the [log](https://gist.github.com/rogelio-blanco/9fa4081db0ee85882d88) I try different approaches but I'm still failing.  Any help or advice are very welcome.

This is my application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is my pom

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<parent>
    <!-- Your own application should inherit from spring-boot-starter-parent -->
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<groupId>com.sample.war</groupId>
<artifactId>project</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>project</name>
<description>Sample Project</description>
<url>www.project.com</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.build.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.outputEncoding>
    <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
    <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>

    <java-version>1.8</java-version>
    <tomcat.version>8.0.24</tomcat.version>
    <org.apache.jclouds-version>1.9.0</org.apache.jclouds-version>
    <com.mysema.querydsl-version>3.6.5</com.mysema.querydsl-version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Boot Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Apache Commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Email -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Lombok -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- HikariCP Connection Pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.9</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$ -->
    </dependency>
    <!-- QueryDSL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>${com.mysema.querydsl-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JClouds -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jclouds-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.jclouds-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.driver</groupId>
        <artifactId>jclouds-sshj</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.jclouds-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JClouds Rackspace US -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.jclouds.labs</groupId>
        <artifactId>rackspace-cloudfiles-us</artifactId>
        <version>${org.apache.jclouds-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Guava -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>18.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.yaml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.yaml</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <processor>com.mysema.query.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
                    <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
                    <version>${com.mysema.querydsl-version}</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>process</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/annotations</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Judging by your log, you're using some custom code (rather than Spring Boot's auto-configuration) to create and configure your Hikari DataSource. It'll be very hard to figure out the problem without seeing that code. Perhaps you can share a minimal example that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After different approaches, I found the error and it was how I create the datasource using Hikari CP.   If you have a similar problem please make sure you datasource config looks like:

```
@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() {
    Properties dsProps = new Properties();
    dsProps.setProperty("url", url);
    dsProps.setProperty("user", username);
    dsProps.setProperty("password", password);

    HikariConfig hc = new HikariConfig();
    hc.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
    hc.setJdbcUrl(url);
    hc.setMaxLifetime(maxLifetime);
    hc.setAutoCommit(autoCommit);
    hc.setConnectionTimeout(connectionTimeout);
    hc.setIdleTimeout(idleTimeout);
    hc.setMinimumIdle(minimumIdle);
    hc.setMaximumPoolSize(maximumPoolSize);
    hc.setPoolName(poolName);

    hc.setDataSourceProperties(dsProps);
    return new HikariDataSource(hc);
}
```

The section that solved the problem was

```
    Properties dsProps = new Properties();
    dsProps.setProperty("url", url);
    dsProps.setProperty("user", username);
    dsProps.setProperty("password", password);
```

and including it

```
hc.setDataSourceProperties(dsProps);
```

I found this approach [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29650501/hikaricp-starts-when-mvn-spring-bootrun-but-not-with-a-deployable-war-file), seems to me that it should be documented in Spring Boot documentation

Comment: Alternatively, you can use ``hc.addDataSourceProperty(name, value)``.